# LINQ to Nhibernate performance

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I'm using a combination of NHibernate and LINQ to try and achieve queries, but I'm worried the following query is pulling back every single user row from the DB, giving a large DB latency, large network traffic, large memory footprint, then filtering it out far too late.

```
public bool CheckEmailAddressIsAvailable
               (string emailAddress, IDataRepository repository)
{
     var users = from user in repository.GetItems<User>()
                 where user.EmailAddress.Equals(
                     emailAddress,
                     System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                 select user;

     return !(users.Any());
}
```

DataRepository is a simple wrapper around NHibernate Session
What I want to know is twofold

1) How can I log all NHibernate SQL that is being created so I can keep an eye on what is being run 
and
2) How can I run the above query to mimic the below SQL

```
select count(*) from [User] where EmailAddress = @emailAddress
```

Comment: i dont use NHibernate but you can use SQL Profiler to look at the queries your app is running. I would also try using .Count != 0 instead of .Any() if you dont think any is implemented

Comment: 1) [howto enable logging of sql][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/474659/671619

Comment: Also, the version of NHibernate you're using is important to note, because v2.1 with the contrib Nhibernate.Linq sucks :(

Answer (score 3):

NHibernate uses log4net for logging, so if you are already using it, one way would be to set the `NHibernate.SQL` logger level to `DEBUG` in your `app.config` file:

```
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

Generally, as with any other application, you can simply use SQL Profiler and log queries for a while.

Regarding your LINQ code, I am pretty sure it creates SQL query similar to yours below, but it's hard to tell without seeing the `GetItems` code.

If this feels slow, you probably need an index on your `EmailAddress` column. The good thing about SQL Profiler is that you can analyze its logs in the Database Engine Tuning Advisor and get recommendations on how to improve it.

Comment: Which level do you put the <logger> tag in your app.config? Ive tried it several places and it just doesnt seem to be able to load the configuration at all when I add it in

Comment: @user1122909: first, you need to define this section by adding `<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>` inside the `<configSections>` element. Then, you need to add the `<log4net>` section where you will define log appenders (file, e-mail, event log), root logger level, and finally add the `<logger>` element. That's why I wrote *if you are already using it*, otherwise it may be easier to simply start SQL Profiler. You should check the [log4net manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

What does GetItems return?
If it is returning anything except IQueryable(<T>), then you are just doing LINQ to Objects (in-memory). And that means loading the whole set.

You have to return an IQueryable to allow DB-side filtering.

Check out the Query<T>() extension method for ISession. That will give you an IQueryable

Comment: So if you return an IQueryable<T> from GetItems and use that in a LINQ expression it will do DB side filtering? Perfect! Just looked at ISession though and theres no Query<T> method. Is this something I need to code up myself?

Comment: As I said, this is an extension method. Check this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666665/nhibernate-where-isession-queryt-is-located